# Why is the conversion of base64 to a PNG image resulting in a black image?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, html5-canvas, python-imaging-library

I have created a paint app using JavaScript and Flask. When I store the images drawn by the user using the `canvas.toDataURL()` and then try to display them together in another `/finish` domain using the PIL, I get a black image as follows:

[image]

This is my code for storing the canvas data on the press of the `Save` button:

```
function save(){
    var filename = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var data = JSON.stringify(canvas_data);
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    var targetX = document.getElementById("targetX").value;
    var targetY = document.getElementById("targetY").value;
    var sizeX = document.getElementById("sizeX").value;
    var sizeY = document.getElementById("sizeY").value;
    
    
    $.post("/", { save_fname: filename, save_cdata: data, save_image: image, save_targetX: targetX, save_targetY: targetY, save_sizeX: sizeX, save_sizeY: sizeY });
    alert(filename + " saved");
    document.getElementById("fname").value = ''
    reset();
}
```

And this is the function I use for decoding the encoding:

```
def stringToRGB(base64_string):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

This is how I call the function:

```
img_arrays.append(stringToRGB(base64_string.split(',')[1]))
```

This is a common error that mainly has the reasons that the user is trying to save them as JPEG images or there's some error with the base54 encoding/decoding but I am not able to find out the exact issue for my code. I used a similar answer (can't find the link) to write the snippets for conversion of the base64 image to a PIL image.

Here's a sample base64 string sample:

```
svg_arr='data:image/png;base64,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'
```

Comment: You are stripping off the `'data:image/png;base64,'` part of your string before you invoke `stringtoRGB`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: JavaScript should give you image in RGB so I don't understand why you use `cv2.cvtColor()` - you don't need it. You would need `cvtColor()` only if you would use `cv2` to read image from file - but you don't use `cv2.imread()`

Comment: I think you would have to show minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - to see where is the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion to remove cv2Color() worked, I was also pasting them on to a dummy background Image I created using `RGB` so I also changed that to `RGBA` and then it worked.